# env['GMAIL_USERNAME'] not being read by rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

so I am trying to send an email when someone fills out a contact us form but when i add:

```
export GMAIL_USERNAME="myapp@domain.com"
export GMAIL_PASSWORD="secret"
```

to my

```
~/.bashrc
```

file, and set my `development.rb` file as below, my app returns a

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required
```

but when i replace `ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"]` & `ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]` in `development.rb` with it's actual values, then i get no problem sending email. doesn't the addition to the `~./bashrc` file ensure that `ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"]` & `ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]` get replaced with the real values? could someone please help??

i've tried [google's instructions](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=14257), but it doesn't work when i use `ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"]` & `ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]` (as opposed to their actual values).

here is the relevant part of my `development.rb` file:

```
  # Raise error if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  # Use SMTP to send mail
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  # Use awesomeness@novulty.com (google app) to send smtp mail
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => "domain", # real domain name in my file
    :user_name            => ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    :password             => ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
    :authentication       => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  # Specify what domain to use for mailer URLs
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
    host: "localhost:3000"
  }
```

thanks!

### UPDATED

my .bashrc file looks like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
export GMAIL_USERNAME=***********
export GMAIL_PASSWORD=***********
```

but when i open the terminal and input `env`, the `GMAIL_*` variables don't get listed but the rvm is added to the `PATH`. this is bothering me... haha.

thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, turns out that my shell wasn't reading the `.bashrc` file so i had to include `source ~/.bashrc` in the `~/.bash_profile` file. Everything worked after that. Thanks @David for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks you tried to write some ruby inside Bash: not allowed.  The correct syntax to set an environment variable is:

```
export GMAIL_USERNAME=myapp@domain.com
```

You can run `env` to verify that it got set correctly.

Comment: actually they were in the format `export GMAIL_USERNAME=myapp@domain.com`. i just messed up in my post. it is corrected above. sorry about that.

but when i run `env` i don't see the variables listed. i've tried restarting my terminal (iTerm2) and still i get nothing